# How to authenticate with username/password in scrapy crawler?

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I want to authenticate Pymongo client with username/password in scrapy crawler.Used this approach but getting error

```
   class MongoDBPipeline(object):
        def __init__(self):
            connection = pymongo.MongoClient(settings['MONGODB_HOST'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
            connection.the_database.authenticate(settings['MONGODB_USERNAME'],settings['MONGODB_PASSWORD'],source='$external', mechanism='PLAIN')
            db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DATABASE']]
            self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
```

Error:

```
 connection.the_database.authenticate(settings['MONGODB_USERNAME'],settings['MONGODB_PASSWORD'],source='$external', mechanism='PLAIN')
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 988, in authenticate
    connect=True)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 397, in _cache_credentials
    sock_info.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 287, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 407, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 329, in _authenticate_plain
    sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 184, in command
    codec_options, check, allowable_errors)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 54, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, msg, allowable_errors)
  File "/home/nikhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 188, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'PLAIN'), ('payload', Binary('\x00nikhil\x00password', 0)), ('autoAuthorize', 1)]) on namespace $external.$cmd failed: no such cmd: saslStart
```

I want to authenticate my code to write it into mongodb.

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
```

Where to put the username and password?

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/authentication.html?highlight=authenticate)?  Are you sure your authentication method used in PyMongo is the same as how you've got your database setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scrapy-mongodb](https://github.com/sebdah/scrapy-mongodb) will be easy to use.

but, in normal way, you need to refference [authentication examples](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html) from python docs of mongodb.

-- refference --

Support For Special Characters In Usernames And Passwords

If your username or password contains special characters (e.g. ‘/’, ‘ ‘, or ‘@’) you must %xx escape them for use in the MongoDB URI. PyMongo uses unquote_plus() to decode them. For example:

```
MongoClient('mongodb://user:' + password + '@127.0.0.1')
```